# Use one application for multiple user in windows server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, multiple-instances

i have a system with windows server, can i install an application (like ArcGis) 
and multiple user can use this application as single instance? 
for more detail, i need use one system for sharing multiple instance of an application on windows. is it possible?

i just have one system with almost 5 user. this user need to interact with specific application on this system in same time (so they cant use remote). how can i manage that? any tools? any approach?

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect question.
Application file is a set of instructions for operating system loaded into memory. Each user can read this set from the same file, but it loads this set into separate piece of memory.

If you have 1MByte .exe file, each running instance will consume 1Mbyte of RAM running this application (it's very not accurate). So if you have 10 users on server, each user running two instances of this application, you will consume 20 Mbytes of RAM and 1MByte of HDD.

You can hit problems with shared data (for example, map images). Some programs are designed to work alone with its set of data and will fail if someone else tries to use its data simultaneously

Comment: your're right, i just have one system with almost 5 user. this user need to interact with specific application on this system. how can i manage that? any tools? any approach?

Comment: What do you mean "iteract". One user starts an app, second user continues to work with it when firs leaves and so on?

Comment: i mean using GUI user interface. yea

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective it depends a lot on the application. A well written application intended for multiple simultaneous users shouldn't have trouble working in the way you state - the entire concept of terminal server/remote desktop services hinges on this. There are of course exceptions, but generally speaking most modern software should be capable of running in multiple instances on the same machine.

Then you have the legal perspective: The license agreement you've entered may not permit you to have multiple users running simultaneous instances of the software even though it's technically possible. That of course is something you need to know before making such a solution available. If that is a permitted use case, you will need to license the right to use Remote Desktop Services, and ensure you have the correct Client Access Licenses, both of which you have to discuss the specifics for with a retailer or license expert.